# iPhone showing iPad xib in Universal app with separate xibs for each

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xib

Ok, this one is WEIRD. I wrote an app more than a year ago and it's been in the App Store and humming along nicely without any real problems. It's a Universal app and I've got a xib for iPhone and a xib for iPad.

Today I got an email from a user saying the UI was no good so I asked for a screenshot. The screenshot shows the iPad xib being displayed with my iPhone tab bar controller. O.o I've never seen this before and we have tens of thousands of users who are using the app just fine. The iPhone users see the iPhone xib and the iPad users see the iPad xib.

What the heck could have even happened here? I've asked her to delete and reinstall the app because it's the only thing I can think of... but how does this happen when everyone else's apps are working just fine?

This is what she is seeing:

[image]

This is what she should see on the iPhone interface:

[image]

This is the iPad interface that is being jammed into the iPhone ui:

[image]